# C, <curl/curl.h> not linking

Tags: c, curl, gcc, linker

I have a 1 file C program as seen below that is attempting to make a simple CURL call. There is also a simplistic Make file.

It looks like my curl/curl.h is not being linked in, causing all references to *curl to be errors.

I used homebrew to install Curl.
Do I need to specify the exact location location for the linker?

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {
    Curl *curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(!curl) {
        printf("curl init failed");
        return 1;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy");

    CURLcode result = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(result != CURLE_OK) {
        printf("curl peform fail");
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 
 
  return 0;
}
```

**ERRORS**

> name@name-MacBook-Pro c % make
>
> ```
> gcc -o main main.c -lcurl 
>
> main.c:10:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Curl'
>
> Curl *curl = curl_easy_init();
> ^ main.c:10:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'curl'
>
> Curl *curl = curl_easy_init();
>       ^ main.c:12:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'curl'
>
> if(!curl) {
>     ^ main.c:17:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'curl'
>
> curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy");
>                  ^ main.c:19:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'curl'
>
> CURLcode result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
>                                     ^ main.c:25:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'curl'
>
> curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 
>                   ^ 6 errors generated. make: *** [all] Error 1
> ```

**CURL CHECK IF INSTALLED**

> name@name-MacBook-Pro c % curl --version curl 7.64.1
> (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0) libcurl/7.64.1 (SecureTransport)
> LibreSSL/2.8.3 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.39.2 Release-Date: 2019-03-27
> Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps
> pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp  Features: AsynchDNS
> GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM
> NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets

Comment: To begin with, `Curl`-> `CURL`

Comment: That solved it, wow. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CURL, not Curl.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(!curl) {
        printf("curl init failed");
        return 1;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy");

    CURLcode result = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(result != CURLE_OK) {
        printf("curl peform fail");
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 

    return 0;
}
```